# Call to a function pointer results in a segfault?

Tags: c++, pointers, dyld

For some reason the following code causes a `SIGSEGV` when I try to call `CFShow_New`:

**The typedef:**

```
typedef void* (*CFShow_XX)(CFTypeRef lol);
```

**The actual code:**

```
ImageLoaderMachO* loader =
dyld::getDyldImage("/XXX/CoreFoundation");

Symbol cfshow_sym = loader->findSymbol("_CFShow");
CFShow_XX* CFShow_New = (CFShow_XX*)cfshow_sym.nl.n_value;

assert(cfshow_sym.nl.n_value == (uint32_t)CFShow);

CFStringRef str = CFSTR("Test123");

CFShow(str); /* Works */
(*CFShow_New)(str); /* SIGSEGV's */
```

What could be the issue? `CFShow` is an `extern "C"`, could that cause it? And if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: it would help if you checked return values instead of assuming they always return != NULL.

Comment: The assertion confirms that the loaded symbol is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the pointer to pointer to function do this:

```
CSShow_XX CFShow_New = (CFShow_XX)cfshow_sym.nl.n_value;
```

and call:

```
CSShow_New(str);
```